# Is my method of generating Initialisation Vector for Cipher Block Chaining secure?

Tags: security, encryption, aes, hmac

In my message I have header containing unique message ID and timestamp (along with some other data) and payload. I sign whole message using HMAC with first key and MD5 or SHA-256 as hash algorythm. Then i use first 16 bytes of signature as IV for encrypting payload with CBC AES with second key. I attach signature to the message.

Is My IV unpredictable enough?
Is signing a plain payload making my security vulnerable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a crypto rather than a programming question.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I disagree, the question is about implementation, creating the IV and signing.

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. By accepting a answer you are indicating to future readers that it is a correct answer.

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Comment: I am afraid James is right. Moving my question to Crypto

Answer (score 2):

Just create the IV with a cryptographic random (CPRNG) function, use it and pre-pend it to the encrypted data for use in decryption.

The signing is unclear, the entire message except the MAC value should be signed, that is any pre-amble, IV, MAC seed and encrypted message, IOW encrypt and then MAC.